# Copying files with even number in its name - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to copy all files from /usr/lib which ends with .X.0.0 where X is an even number. Is there a better way than the following one to select all the files?

```
ls /usr/lib | grep "[02468].0.0$"
```

My problem with this solutions is that in case there are files with names like "xy.800.0.0" I need to use the bracket three times etc.

Comment: Do all the numbers need to be even? That is, does `blah.512.0.0` match or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a glob expansion to match the files:

```
cp /usr/lib/*.*[02468].0.0 /path/to/destination
```

The shell expands this pattern to the list of files before passing them as arguments to `cp`.

Since you tagged Bash, you can make the match more strict by using an extended glob:

```
shopt -s extglob failglob
cp /usr/lib/*.*([0-9])[02468].0.0 /path/to/destination
```

This matches 0 or more other digits followed by an even digit, and doesn't run the command at all if no files match.

Answer (score 0):

You could use extended grep regular expressions to only match even numbers:

```
ls -1q /usr/lib | grep -E "\.[0-9]*[02468].0.0$"
```

However, as Tom suggested, there are better options than parsing the output of ls. It's generally safer and faster to use glob expansion, and more maintainable to just [put everything in a python script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129120/162359).

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks easily e.g. if a filename contains a space. You can achieve the same "strict" match in Bash using an extended glob (I updated my answer to show how).

Comment: By "breaks" I mean that the output cannot be used as a list of arguments to another command.

Comment: After looking into it more, I agree.